# Reading a file already open in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

In my logger application  I need to open file for logging.I close the stream when application closes.However,i need to support reading the content of log file too.So when i try to open the log file i encounter IsolatedStorageException-"Operation not permitted on Isolatestoragefilestream"

here is the sample code:

log file creation :

```cs
IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    file.CreateDirectory("/log");                
    var stream = file.OpenFile("/log/sample.log", 
    System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

log entry code:

```cs
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");
    stream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    stream.Flush();
```

I might need to read the contents:

```cs
IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
//here i encounter isolated storage exception
    var stream = file.OpenFile("/log/sample.log", System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
    System.IO.FileAccess.Read,System.IO.FileShare.Read); <br>
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];<br>
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

I was just trying to open a sample file in readwrite mode and again open it in read mode seperately,still i get same error.In wp7,can't we read file while it is open?(i mean...without closing the stream when it is first open>).

Please let me know any suggestions.

Comment: Can you make a copy of a file and read that?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix the issue, but when opening the file to read it, you should use the `System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite` sharing mode instead of `System.IO.FileShare.Read`. `FileShare.Read` tells the system to allow the file to be open concurrently only in reading mode. However, you already have the file open in writing mode, so it cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change read operation flag. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) article:

> **Read**  Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading.

In your case it is preferable to use ReadWrite mode:

> **ReadWrite** Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing.

Comment: Yes..it is correct.I've already opened file for reading.So i need to change my flag.thanks.

Comment: I had already opened file in FileShare.ReadWrite during opening and again when I try to read I provided only FileShare.Read if I change it to FileShare.ReadWrite it worked.

Comment: Oh, I was just tired when I was asking about flags. I thought you are talking about flags in here.

Answer (score 0):

According to me:

open file read and write mode on app launch and use same file instance for reading and writing file contents. Means don't open file separately for reading and writing.

Comment: Yes..it is also a possible solution.But ,i was looking for that way as i need to support reading of the log file from different file api which is not aware of logging.